# Why am I getting an assertion error?

Tags: visual-c++, assertions

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 int size = 0;
 int* myArray = new int [size + 1];
 cout << "Enter the exponent of the first term: ";
 cin >> size;
 cout << endl;
 for (int i = size; i >= 0; --i)
 {
  cout << "Enter the coefficient of the term with exponent " 
   << i << ": ";
  cin >> myArray[i];
 }
 for (int i = size; i >= 0; --i)
 {
  cout << i << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting an assertion error on input greater than 2?  This is the precursor to a polynomial program where the subscript of the array is the power of each term and the element at array[subscript] is the coefficient.

Comment: What in the world is that code trying to do? You initialize myArray as an array with only 1 int in it, then read size, and try to write to that arbitrary location in the array?

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Initially I just got a compile error and initialized  size to 0 without thinking to clear the error.  But that created a run-time error.  I fixed it by not initializing size and allocating the myArray after I input size.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: @Brandon: One more thing, your for loop is starting from `int i = size;` that will be an invalid index. It should start from `size-1`

Comment: @Naveen: I allocated the array with size + 1 so it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is allocated to be an int[1].  It needs to be allocated *after* you read in the size value.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your array when size = 0, giving an array size of 1
You get your assertion error when you go outside of the array bounds (1).

Answer (score 0):

myArray always has size 0 + 1 = 1. i starts out at whatever the user inputted, and the first array access you make is myArray[i]. So, say the user inputs 5, your array has size 1 and you access myArray[5]. It will fail!

I would allocate the array AFTER you input size.